# Cloud Firestore security rule suddenly not working despite being logged in

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have the following Firestore database rule:

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Which is copy and pasted directly from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

This rule had been working for a long time, but after updating some packages (Angular 12.0.5, Firebase ^8.6.8, Angular Fire ^6.1.5, etc.), it suddenly started giving me the following error in the browser despite being logged into the same account I always use:

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

If I switch `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` to `allow read, write: if true` then it begins to work again.

I have the following code in my app, which returns my auth user with all the correct data prior to getting that error message, so I know that I am logged in, so why is my rule not working anymore?

```
this.afAuth.user.subscribe(user => {
  console.log('user from afAuth subscribe', user);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are trying to access Firestore before the user has sufficiently authenticated, you can check this with the AngularFire version of `Auth().currentUser != null`

if this is not the case, this would be a Bug within Angular Fire and should be prompted through their support forums as well as downgrading to a previous version.

Comment: I reverted back to a previous version for Angular Fire and was still having the same problem, but I reverted back to version 8.5 of Firebase and the problem went away. I don't know if that means it's a bug with Firebase, or if it's just a compatibility issue between versions of Angular Fire and Firebase.

Comment: most likely a compatibility issue between the two, the latest Angular Fire might be compatible with only the newest Beta but it's not worth looking into until it's full production ready